# A Imageview's "touch area rect" remains after it has been animated to move elsewhere

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, cabasicanimation

I'm moving an image with CABasicAnimation, but I've noticed that its rect for touch events remain at its old position - How can I update the rect so it doesn't register at the wrong place?

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation; 
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
theAnimation.duration=0.3;
theAnimation.repeatCount=0;
theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
theAnimation.autoreverses=NO;
theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-rect.size.width*0.9];
[self.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

Comment: How are you handling the touch area for this?  Core animation layers don't have an inherent understanding of being touched, so you are likely either manually checking touch events or you are using a gesture recognizer.   Can you post more information on how you're doing this?

Comment: @gaige I have subclassed UIImage view like this: `@interface TouchImageView : UIImageView` and then I implemented `touchesBegan:withEvent` and set `self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: OK, but you're animating the layer here, not the view, so how are you determining if the touch is in the CALayer?  Or did you intend to movie the view?   If you are tying to move the view instead of the layer of the view, you need to animate the view, not the view's layer.

Comment: honestly, I thought it was the same thing... That you animated a view by going through its layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to be moving the `TouchImageView` subclass of the `UIImageView`, not `self.layer`.   The latter is a lower-level drawing surface, but not what handles the touch events, etc.

From [iPad: Move UIView with animation, then move it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899067/ipad-move-uiview-with-animation-then-move-it-back), here's some adapted code that animates the `translation` property as you were doing:

```
CGFloat moveX = -rect.size.width*0.9;
CGFloat moveY = 0;

[UIView beginAnimations: @"Move View" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.3 ];
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(moveX,moveY);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You should, however, be able to simplify this by just changing the frame of the view:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
newFrame.x -=rect.size.width*0.9;

[UIView beginAnimations: @"Move View" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.3 ];
self.frame = newFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```